# Не работает remove(i)

Tags: python

Сделал программу которая удаляет из парных чисел списка все которые кратные 3, но оно то удаляет то нет

```
import random
list=random.sample(range(1,20),10)
print(list)
par=[]
for i in list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        par.append(i)

print(par)
for i in par:
   if i % 3 == 0:
      par.remove(i)

print(par)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а вы оригинал :)

удалять из списка по которому при этом еще и двигаетесь - тут последствия вообще непредсказуемые могут быть!

вам по хорошему надо или на каждый `remove` начинать свой новый `for` или просто собрать новый вектор

```
res = [i for i in par if i % 3 != 0]
```

ну или через `filter`

```
res = filter(lambda i: i % 3 != 0, par)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вот скину скорее всего Ваш вариант. Но я уже свой успел накалякать(просто создал список где добаляю все числа которые !=0)

Comment: А ваша задача была создать список где числа только кратные 2 и не кратные 3?

Comment: ну просто из списка убрать все непарные числа, и уже из парных удалить всё что кратно 3

Comment: непарные - это судя по коду - нечётные? :)

Comment: `res = [i for i in list if i % 3 != 0 and i % 2 == 0]`

Comment: да нечётные. Вот и новое слово на русском выучил :D

Comment: сразу вспомнился анекдот про "-Хлопцы, де тут у вас останивка? -Зупынка за кутом, а ты, москалику, прийихав!" :) теперь еще на одно украинское слово знаю больше :)

Comment: кстати, а если нужно удалить из списка а не делать новый, то как нужно писать?(читал про pop(но не сложилось с ним)

Comment: нельзя идти по списку и удалять разные объекты , такое и в c++  с итераторами и удаление по итератору и т.д., по идее можно пройти по индексам от конца в начало и удалять по индексам, но когда идете сначала в конец и удаляете - это нарушает индексацию в списка и как раз получается, что может так случится, что что-то правильно удалит, а что-то нет. Т.е. вы удаляете элемент, следующий элемент каким будет? `index + 1` по идее уже на последующий, а не на следующий указывает

Comment: Понял, спасибо!